# How does Gogo's meteor hammer work?

Tags: kill-bill

How on earth does Gogo activate and detract the round metal blade that surrounds her meteor hammer during the fight against The Bride in *Kill Bill*?

From what I can see there's no mechanism that activates it other than the button on the handle, but how does it work? There's only a chain between the ball and handle.

[image: gogo hammer]

Comment: One word: Bluetooth.  The button in the handle is connected to a bluetooth transmitter, which is paired exclusively to a receiver in the ball.  When triggered, the receiver activates a separate mechanism that extends to retracts the blades.

Comment: The phones and tech of the time wouldn't allow for it

Comment: Bluetooth is not only for smartphones. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) the Bluetooth wireless technology specification was officially invented in 1994. The name "Bluetooth" was coined in 1998. [Kill Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_Bill:_Volume_1) was released in 2003, and nothing to indicate the movie wasn't set in present time. **Details aside,** I fully admit that my remark was nonsense. I pulled it out of my @$$ in much the same way as the blades appeared from Gogo's magic ninja weapon. That's why I left it as a comment rather than a real answer =P

Comment: Radio frequency remote controls are even older than bluetooth

Answer (score 4):

Maybe she activated it with a button which sends a small electrical sign to the ball.

The handle can generate it with using a small battery or a capacitor which can produce and supply small amount of electrical energy with using swinging energy of the ball.

After the button is pressed and the electrical sign reaches the ball, then the mechanism is warned and metal blades are triggered.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We are never told, but there are a few options:

- [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth):

> The development of the "short-link" radio technology, later named Bluetooth, was initiated in 1989. Bluetooth is a standard wire-replacement communications protocol primarily designed for low-power consumption, with a short range based on low-cost transceiver microchips in each device.

- [Remote Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_control)

> In electronics, a remote control is a component of an electronic device used to operate the device wirelessly from a distance. For example, in consumer electronics, a remote control can be used to operate devices such as a television set, DVD player, or other home appliance, from a short distance. A remote control is primarily a convenience feature for the user, and can allow operation of devices that are out of convenient reach for direct operation of controls. In some cases, remote controls allow a person to operate a device that they otherwise would not be able to reach.

- [Radio Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_control)

> Radio control (often abbreviated to R/C or simply RC) is the use of radio signals to remotely control a device. Radio control is used for control of model vehicles from a hand-held radio transmitter. Industrial, military, and scientific research organizations make use of radio-controlled vehicles as well. In 1894, the first example of wirelessly controlling at a distance was during a demonstration by the British physicist Oliver Lodge.